# How do I grant access to a registration page only for users given a certain link within an e-mail?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using swift mailer and I want to provide a link in the e-mail that leads to an account registration page.

I only want to grant access to the user has the link in the email, but make sure that no one can go to the registration page typing in the path to the URL bar.

I researched and learned about using some kind of access token but have been stuck for a while.

Comment: just put a unique key\value in the url that you email, and check for that on the registration page

Answer (score 0):

I think the Access Token is the way you should go for.

There is no way you can make an URL work by clicking on it in the email but by no other mean, what if the people copy that URL from the email and paste it to the URL bar, what if they remember it and type it themselves on the bar ? I believe it should still function the same all the time.

I believe what should be implemented is:

-- Each email should contain a single unique url having an unique **Access Token**.

-- An **Access Token** should belong to a single user only.

-- An **Access Token** should have expired after a specific amount of time.

-- An **Access Token** should be invalidated immediately after the user finish the task they need to do in the registration page.

-- To be more secure, an **Access Token** can have a limited number of attempts, so for example, after three attempts but the tasks required are still not complete, the Access Token should become invalid and can no longer be used.

Comment: Thanks!! Where and how do I put the access token?

Comment: In Laravel you can define it as model, the token can be generated as an unique string when you send out the email and append to the URL that you put inside the email. The token model should have 1-1 relationship with your User model and attributes to show when it's created, whether it's valid and how many attempts has been made to use it